# How to install operating system from ISO image through TFTP and PXE?

Tags: iso-image, tftp

TFTPD64 is installed on the computer that has the .iso file for operating system. I extracted the contents of .iso into a local folder. In TFTPD64 I have to enable DHCP server, even though there's already one on the network, since client doesn't detect and get an IP info.

For Boot File under DHCP settings in TFTPD64 I don't know what to put.

I tried putting BOOT.CAT, but client just downloaded the file quickly and didn't do anything with it. I tried putting the name of the entire .iso image itself but TFTPD64 said under the status of the download "ERR".

How to install an OS from ISO image file using TFTPD64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That might not be possible.

Typically when netbooting a small image gets downloaded through tftp (that contains network drivers and and a *very* basic operating system) and then it will connect to a network drive that contains the rest of the files needed to boot.

Because of the file size limitations of TFTP, and the fact that the ISO needs to be stored somewhere while the computer boots - you can't just boot an ISO over the network.

What are you trying to boot over the network? If it's linux you may want to take a look at the linux terminal server project. It's a great way to learn about tftp and the like. If it's windows, the windows automated install kit is another cool project to learn.

Comment: Trying to install ESXI 5.5 on a computer. I can do it via DVD image but wanted to try PXE once in my life.

Comment: Oh! That might actually be possible then - You'll still have to extract some files from the ISO, but yeah - ESXI is pretty small... Have you read this at all? https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.install.doc_50%2FGUID-5B132E25-0CFC-40D0-993D-40A83981E0E5.html